# How to delete a svn-brach but not its sub-branches?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branch

I have a little problem with SVN. 
Before, please look at the image.

[image]

I created a new branch named **carlosTest** from **desarrollo**(The last branch is VERY important), but when i looked at the graphic everything was the opposite: the branch desarrollo looks as if it comes from carlosTest, but the main branch is desarrollo, no carlosTest.

Now, I must to delete carlosTest, but i'm afraid.

If I delete the carlosTest, desarrollo can be delete too? 
How can i solve it?

Thanks my friends

Comment: I suggest you to check the svn logs on `branches` folder to be sure of what you've done regarding the branches. Then don't be afraid to commit the deletion of  branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your graph is cut off, but it looks like your branches are organized like:

```
project
|_branches/carlosTest
|_branches/desarrollo
```

Which means no, at this point these branches are separated and can be deleted. It's important to note that nothing is actually "deleted" from a repository. They can always be recovered, as that is the entire purpose of the versioning system. :)

The only way you would have a problem is if you had it like this:

```
project
|_branches/desarrollo
               |_carlosTest
```

In which, that would be a sub-directory, not a branch.

It's also worth noting since you mentioned it in the OP, that desarrollo only looks like it came from carlosTest because of how the graph is oriented. The lines show them branch from a singular point. They're only stacked like that because carlosTest has the latest commit, so it's on top of the list. The lines themselves show the hierarchy.

Comment: Thank  a lot, 
I removed carlosTest without any problem.
:)